# cannot use AND with the same argument in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
select producten_pid from prodsymp where symptomen_id = 11 and symptomen_id = 18;
```

I am trying the select statement above on a mysql table.
But I am not getting any results, where I should.
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your answers.
The idea was to create a database for problems and solutions, 
where one problem can have multiple solutions and one solution can solve multiple problems.
I created this reference table 'probsol' with references to both the problems and the solutions table like below.

```
psid    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  
 pid    11  11  12  12  17  18  18  19  20  
 sid    18  9   18  10  10  18  9   13  13
```

Now I am trying to create a query to find lets say a single solution to multiple problems as below:

```
select sid from prodsymp where pid = 11 and pid = 12;
```

The results for this query should be 18, but I am getting 0 results.

Comment: should use “or”

Comment: It seems you lack understanding of relational databases. I suggest you look up a tutorial about relational models and queries.

Comment: Thanks RalfFriedl for your comment, but I do have some knowledge of relational databases. And what I put here is not the entire program but a simplification of the part that I cannot solve and cannot find in any tutorial. Hence my reach out to this platform. I am trying to find a way around the lack of functionality of mysql.

Comment: Simply replacing AND with OR will not achieve what it sounds like he wants. He may need to join the table to itself or something.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql is working as expected. You ask for a row where `symptomen_id` is at the same time 11 and 18. There can be no such row, so you don't get any result.

Maybe you wanted to use `OR`.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong. `symptomen_id` can't be both at the same time. Use `or`.

Even better, use `in` like so:

```
select producten_pid from prodsymp where symptomen_id in (11, 18).
```

---

Edit:

Afer you edited your question, your problem became quite different.

Maybe this query can help:

```
SELECT
    sid,
    count(*) as cnt   
FROM
    producten_pid    
where
    pid in (
        11,12
    )    
group by
    sid    
having
    count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks Roman, but the 'IN' condition will not solve my problem, although it comes close.